# How to assign function's output array to a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Below is my simplified code where it's giving me errors. It's probably a very simple thing but it's making me confused.

```
class MyController extends ParentController {
  public $pet_list = $this->pet_list_array(); 
  //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ......

  public function pet_list_array() {        
    return array('cat'=>'Steve\'s Cat', 
                 'dog'=>'Fiona\'s Dog',
                 'lion'=>'John\'s Lion');
  }
}
```

If I do this instead, I get a different error

```
public $pet_list = pet_list_array(); 
//Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in.....
```

But if I do this `public $pet_list = pet_list_array;` (without the round brackets after the function name), it seems to work fine. Is this a normal behaviour? I am a bit unsure.

Comment: You can only use scalar values, arrays and `null` as default. You can find this info on the PHP manual AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't make a call to a class method in the class definition. Make a __construct() method and set it there, like so:

```
class MyController extends ParentController {
  public $pet_list;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->pet_list = $this->pet_list_array();
  }

  public function pet_list_array() {        
    return array('cat'=>'Steve\'s Cat', 
                 'dog'=>'Fiona\'s Dog',
                 'lion'=>'John\'s Lion');
  }
}
```

Of course, you probably don't need both $pet_list and pet_list_array() in the same class if they return the same value all the time.